# How can I get the ping results (like roundtrip time and ping status) when I ping to multiple IP's at the same time with PingAsync?

Tags: c#, ping

I have following Code-1 for pinging to single IP and get the ping results. It is working as expected. Now I want to ping to multiple IP's (just few, not hundred of IP's) at the same time, and get their results.

I have written Code-2 but I don't know how to get the results like roundtrip time and ping status for each ping process. In Code1 I got these from the var reply. But in Code2 I don't know how to fetch them?

Code1*****

```
private async ValueTask PingMachine(string ipadress, string iptype)
{
    var timesToPing = 4;
    var counter = 1;
    while (counter <= timesToPing)
    {
        var reply = await Pinger(ipadress);
        TagService.log_Win.AppendLine($"Pinged {ipadress} {counter} times time:{reply.RoundtripTime} status: {reply.Status.ToString()}");
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

private async ValueTask<PingReply>
Pinger(string ipAddress)
{
    var ping = new Ping();
    var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ipAddress);
    return reply;
}
```

Code2*****

```
public static string[] addresses = { "10.92.114.73", "10.92.114.74", "10.92.114.75" };
private async Task<List<PingReply>> Pinger2()
{
    var tasks = addresses.Select(ip => new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 2000));
    var reply = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return reply.ToList();
}
```

Update2******

```
var replies = await Pinger2();
        foreach (var r in replies)
            {
            TagService.log_Win.AppendLine(replies.Select(r => r.RoundtripTime).ToString());
            }

private async Task<IEnumerable<PingReply>> Pinger2()
 {
   var tasks = addresses.Select(async ip => await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 2000));
   var replies = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   return replies;
 }
```

Comment: Code 2 will not work because then is nothing that indicates when all pings get replies.  The "await" doesn't get any indications when the last ping gets replied.  With Ping you may never get a reply from an invalid IP (or device is turned off) so you need a timer to indicate when you stop waiting for an IP.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the answer. Could you give a small hint where to place the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `await` within the lambda

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<PingReply>> Pinger2()
{
    var tasks = addresses.Select(async ip => await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 2000));
    var replies = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return replies;
}
```

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot. But how can I get the "RoundtripTime" for each IP-Ping process? (For one IP I read it over reply.RoundtripTime)

Comment: Use Linq or a foreach `var replies = await Pinger2(); replies.Select(r => r.RoundtripTime).Dump();` something like that

Comment: I think I am very near to the solution :-) I have updated my code under Update2. I think I have just problem with replies.Select(r => r.RoundtripTime).Dump(). I get Compile Error with Dump(), so I have written .toString(). But this didin't work Instead of  RoundtripTime I got  System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply,System.Int64]

Comment: OK what do actually want to do with the results? `.Dump` is just an example, for LinqPad or similar, so probably not relevant. Maybe `foreach (var reply in replies) { TagService.log_Win.AppendLine($"Pinged {reply.Address} time:{reply.RoundtripTime} status: {reply.Status}"); }` or something? It's just a list, you need to loop it like you would any other list

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience. It worked like a charm! :-)